# How can $-y\geq 0$ imply $y\leq 0$ in an ordered vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, order-theory

The following is an excerpt from a Wikipedia article about [ordered vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_vector_space):

> Given an ordered vector space $(V,\geq)$, the subset $V^+$ of all elements $x$ in $V$ satisfying $x≥0$ is a convex cone, called the positive cone of $V$. Since the partial order $≥$ is antisymmetric, one can show, that $V^+∩(−V^+)=\{0\}$, hence $V^+$ is a proper cone. That it is convex can be seen by combining the above two axioms with the transitivity property of the (pre)order.

I don't see how one can get $V^+∩(−V^+)=\{0\}$. Following the definition, suppose $y\in V^+\cap (-V^+)$, then

- $y\geq 0$ since $y\in V^+$
- $y=-x$ for some $x\geq 0$ (i.e. $x\in V^+$ by definition) since $y\in -V^+$.

I can *formally* manipulate the inequalities to reach the conclusion but I cannot convince myself using just the definitions and axioms of the ordered vector space:

> $y=-x$ and $x\geq 0$ imply that $-y\geq 0$ (one can deduce this by noting that $-y=(-1)y=(-1)(-x)=x$). Then $y\leq 0$ (formally). But we have $y\geq 0$ also. Therefore by antisymmetricity we have $y=0$.

Here is my **question**:

By what axiom can one deduce $y\leq 0$ from $-y\geq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because $\ge $ is compatible with addition:
$-y\ge 0$ implies $y+(-y)\ge y+0$. As $y+(-y)=0$ be definition of additive inverse and $y+0=y$ by neutral element property, we obtain $0\ge y$.